# similar font to FreeHand 521

Tags: font-identification

Was trying to find a font type that looks like this:

[image: Example image]

All I could find was [FreeHand 521](https://docs.google.com/open?id=1umMFYPzPfyFLxBc4zncyckSet-Q8EwANuDVX1tDQSosliysuI5gaSZoHeN2F):

[image: FreeHand font image]

[WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) gave me no relevant results. Has anyone seen such font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is indeed Freehand 521 (which seems to be related Ludlow Mandate) with effects applied to broaden the stroke. The underlying geometry seems the same.